# SpheroJS Command sync response was lost OSX

Tags: node.js, sphero

I am facing the issues with the spherojs npm package where OSX is unable to get a response back from BB8 once a command is issued:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Command sync response was lost.
    at Sphero.handler (/Users/shah/projects/node/ai8/node_modules/sphero/lib/sphero.js:252:21)
From previous event:
    at Sphero.command (/Users/shah/projects/node/ai8/node_modules/sphero/lib/sphero.js:180:10)
    at Sphero.device.setRgbLed    (/Users/shah/projects/node/ai8/node_modules/sphero/lib/devices/sphero.js:369:12)
    at Sphero.device.color (/Users/shah/projects/node/ai8/node_modules/sphero/lib/devices/custom.js:168:19)
    at file:///Users/shah/projects/node/ai8/js/orb.js:7:7[0m
```

My current environment is:

```
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.11.6
BuildVersion:   15G31

node -v
v6.9.5

npm -v 
3.10.10

 system_profiler SPBluetoothDataType | sed -n "/Apple Bluetooth Software Version\:/,/Manufacturer\:/p" | tr -s "    [\n]" "[ ]" | sed "s:.*Address\: ::g" | sed "s: Manufacturer\:.*::g" | grep "[[:graph:]]"

80-E6-50-1B-50-31 Bluetooth Low Energy Supported: Yes Handoff Supported: Yes Instant Hot Spot Supported:        Yes
```

Any ideas what could be causing this, the Nodejs app is able to connect to the droid and send the command, the command is executed and then the connection to bb8 is lost where the Nodejs application does not get a response back for command sync.

Thanks in advance for your inputs!

Comment: Possible workarround:

https://github.com/orbotix/sphero.js/issues/85